# Ckeditor не отображает форматирование

Tags: ckeditor

Установил Ckeditor 4.3.
Отключил allowedContent чтобы не резал теги.
Теги не режет, но и не отображает форматирование.
Т.е. в исходном коде теги есть, например class = grey, но в режиме просмотра текст совсем не серый.
При выходе из редактора текст серенький, как надо.
Вообщем как сделать чтобы редактор отображал текст согласно CSS, а то, пока не откроешь исходный текст и не поймешь какого он цвета, шрифта...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто пропиши в файле config.js такую строчку с указанием твоего файла стилей:

```
config.contentsCss = ['/style/style.css' , '/ckeditor/contents.css'];
```

Тут будут загружаться и родные стили эдитора и твои...только путь поправь к файлу...